# 「数値上ほぼ等しい場合」という条件を立てる方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby

「数値上ほぼ等しい場合」という条件を立てる方法を教えていただきたいです．

実数の計算を行うと，どうしても数値計算誤差が生じてしまいます．
例えば，
`0.027` という値が，`0.027000000000000003`という感じです．

ここで，上記の例では数値計算誤差が生じているだけで，実際は等しいはずです，
そこで，例えば，

```
a = 0.027
b = 0.027000000000000003
```

とするときに，

```
if a == b
```

がtrueになるようにしたいということです．

方法がわからないのでご教授いただきたいです.

（追記）

```
a = 0.027
b = 0.026000000000000002 # => b = 0.027999999999999997 でもfalse
```

のときは，falseと判定したいです．

Comment: bigdecimal [module function Kernel.#BigDecimal (Ruby 2.6.0)](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Kernel/m/BigDecimal.html) で有効桁数を指定する方法が考えられます。例えば有効桁数を3桁にする場合は `BigDecimal(a, 3) == BigDecimal(b, 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

仮に有効数字を揃えて比較したいという場合であれば、以下の方法があるかもしれません。

```
a = 0.027
b = 0.027000000000000003
```

```
a.round(16) == b.round(16) # 丸める位は適当です。
# => true
```

浮動小数点演算に誤差が生じてしまうのはある程度仕方ない部分もあると思うので、それを発生させない工夫も必要かもしれません。

参考: https://doruby.jp/users/note/entries/1

これは手っ取り早い解決方法なので、より正確を期すなら他の方の回答も参考してみるといいと思います。（ど、どなたか…。）

（追記）

BigDecimal と Float::EPSILON を使えば、以下のようにも比較できそうです。

```
(BigDecimal("1.0") - BigDecimal("1.00000000000000000000003")).abs < Float::EPSILON
# => true
```

Ruby のリファレンスマニュアルによると、Float::EPSILON は「1.0 + Float::EPSILON != 1.0 となる最小の正の値です。」とのことです。つまり、めちゃくちゃ小さい数ということです。
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.6.0/class/Float.html#C_-E-P-S-I-L-O-N

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．現状では，回答していただいた内容で大丈夫でした．

Comment: ありがとうございます。 @eduidl さんも回答してる通り、差分の絶対値が限りなく 0 に近いかどうかの判定をする方法も良さそうです。

Comment: `Float::EPSILON`を使う場合、1より少し大きな値を比較するだけでも、二進浮動小数点演算に伴う誤差がそれより大きくなってしまうので、「数値上ほぼ等しい場合」と言う条件には当てはまらない結果が出てしまいます。`(BigDecimal("27") - BigDecimal("27.000000000000003")).abs < Float::EPSILON`は`false`になります。また質問内容は二進での演算誤差を問題にしているので、誤差範囲以内かを求めるのに`BigDecimal`を使用するのは意味がありません。eduidlさんの回答のように、そのまま差の絶対値を用い、演算数の大きさと必要とされる精度に応じて「許容誤差」を決めるべきです。

Answer (score 8):

状況に依りますが，以下のようにBigDecimalを使い，そもそも誤差が生まれないようにするという手もあります．

```rb
require 'bigdecimal'

puts 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
#=> false
puts BigDecimal('0.1') + BigDecimal('0.2') == BigDecimal('0.3')
#=> true
```

これは，お金のような無限の精度を持った数を扱うような場合にはよく使われる方法です．
BigDecimalを使うべきでない場合（科学計算等）には，以下のようにします．

```rb
a = 0.027
b = 0.027000000000000003
puts (a - b).abs < 1e-10
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Epsilon を取り扱う場合、絶対値と比較するのではなく、相対誤差に変換してから計算することをお勧めします。

というのも、浮動小数点数の誤差は、絶対値ではなく、有効桁数的な、その数値のスケールに対する相対値でもって規定されるからです。

なので:

```rb
a = 0.027
b = 0.027000000000000003

p (((a - b) / a).abs < 10 * Float::EPSILON)
```

が個人的にはおすすめです。ここで出てきた 10 はどれぐらいの浮動小数演算による誤差を許容するかの係数で、必要に応じて調整します。一般的に、浮動小数演算を繰り返すほど、誤差は大きくなる可能性があります。